# date_add/dateadd Athena/Redshift like function for spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, dateadd

I was wondering whether there is any function similar to athena/redshift date_add/dateadd which can be used to add milliseconds to timestamp. For e.g. I have timestamp value as 2020-05-12 10:23:45 and no millisecond part. Is there a way to add millisecond to timestamp apart from using INTERVAL? 
Athena example

`date_add('millisecond', <column-with-bigint-data>, <column-with-timestamp-data-without-millisecond>)`

If I have 2020-05-12 10:23:45 and 1115687 then adding 1115687 to above timestamp in Athena gives me 2020-05-12 10:23:45.687

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this in the past using a simple UDF.
The best thing about this is-

- Easily customizable logic for either addition or subtraction or any other arithmetic operation
- Since getTime() returns mili-seconds since 1st jan,1970, you can use TimeUnit.Days.toMillis() in case of days or similar implementations to handle any kind of input. Like in this case we are taking miliseconds as input.

Code -

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat    

// Creating a UDF that takes DATE TIME & Time Interval as input 
val datetime_add = udf((x: String, y: Int) => {
    val datetimeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    val result = new Date(datetimeformat.parse(x).getTime() + y)
  datetimeformat.format(result)
} )
//Creating a DataFrame with DateTime and 
val df = Seq((1, "2020-05-12 10:23:45", 5000), (2, "2020-11-11 12:12:12", 2000)).toDF("id", "DateTime", "miliseconds")

df.show()
//Creating a new column which will hold the new Time i.e the added time 
df.withColumn("new_Date", datetime_add($"DateTime", $"miliseconds")).show()
```

Output -

[image]

Please let me know if this answers your question or not.
IMPORTANT - I am running this snippet on Databricks.

References -

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html
2. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/date_gettime.htm